# On the iPhone, how can I make the icon badge?

Tags: iphone, icons

I want to set an icon badge while I am not in the application, like the Mail application.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

From within your application you can use the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property of `UIApplication` to set the badge number:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

If you want to change the badge without the user launching your app, you need to use the push notification service.  The [Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) should have all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone SDK doesn't support that functionality yet. It can only be done on a jailbroken device.

EDIT: Sorry that's not ENTIRELY true, you can do it with the 'push' function but only apps that are screened by Apple are allowed at this stage.

EDIT AGAIN: Nope I'm completely wrong try this

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 2;
```

Comment: Really? I'm not an iphone developer, but I have a couple of non-jailbroken, non-push apps that set the icon badge.

Comment: You know what, your right... I must have been thinking of something else. Cheers.