# Dynamically change iphone app icon and loading image

Tags: iphone

I would like to update the application icon and the splash (loading) screen of my app dynamically if possible, by storing the data in SQLite fetched from a webservice

I pretty sure the answer is going to be no but thought I'd get confirmation

Thanks

Comment: You can set the app icon badge without push notifications. See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157202/on-the-iphone-how-can-i-make-the-icon-badge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* change the Default.png file by putting a symlink in your app bundle:

http://collison.ie/blog/2008/11/dynamic-defaultpng-files-on-the-iphone

The same technique *might* work for the Icon.png, but I doubt it, and if you could get it to work I imagine you'd have to HUP the SpringBoard (which you can't do on a non-jailbroken device).

It looks like Apple has removed the ability to set a badge for your app other than through push notifications (which in that case can only be a number according to the docs).

EDIT: This hole was closed in 3.0:

[Dynamic (Default.png) splashscreen in 3.0 [iPhone SDK]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959080/dynamic-default-png-splashscreen-in-3-0-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Thanks Frank, seems that they may have capped it though in 3.X SDKs