# IOS modify launch icon

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically change iphone app icon and loading image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097807/dynamically-change-iphone-app-icon-and-loading-image)

Hi, I would like to know if it is possible for an application to modify it's launch icon on a daily basis similar to the calendar app.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not possible under the current SDK for an Appstore app. The best you can do is change the red badge like how the Mail.app displays the number of unread emails.